# R: If statement within for loop does not seem to be working?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I have the following dataset:

[image: dataset]

I want to go through the ID's in the `action_ID` column and check if it is in the `value` column. If it is, I want to see if the associated variable is a `Comment` or not. If it is a `Comment`, I will add 1 to the count of the number of comments for that ID into a new data frame, called `final`, which consists of the `action_ID` and number of comments.

This is the code I have written so far:

```
final = data.frame(action_ID = c(1001,981,734,985))

for (x in shares$action_ID) {
    if ((x %in% shares$value) & (shares$variable[shares$value == x] =="Comment")){
      final$num_comments[final$action_ID == x] =+ 1
    }else {
       final$num_comments[final$action_ID == x]  =+ 0
   }
}
```

Whenever I run it doesn't work. I tried to debug it by just looking at the first condition in the if-statement and it turns out for some reason the if statement isn't really working. Every value in `action_ID` gets outputted. I also try using any which didn't work either.

```
for (x in shares$action_ID){
    print(x)
    if (any(shares$value == x)){ # & (shares$variable[shares$value == x]== "Comment")){
        print(x)

    }
}
```

output:

```
[1] "734"
[1] "1001"
[1] "1001"
[1] "985"
[1] "981"
```

Thanks for any help!!

EDIT:
I don't think I was very clear about the output, I am trying to create a table that will give a count of the number of posts that have 0 comments, 1 comment, 2 comments, etc.

Comment: It's better to share your data (or parts of it) using `dput` instead of posting an image of it

Comment: `t <- table(df$action_ID[df$variable == 'Comment']); data.frame(t)` or if you need all the IDs `t <- table(factor(df$action_ID)[df$variable == 'Comment']); data.frame(t)`

Answer (score 0):

Using a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data_frame(action_ID = c(734, 1001, 985, 981),
                 variable = c("Photo", "Post", "Share", "Comment"),
                 value = c(234, 345, 1001, 1001))

# add the cnt variable before hand
df$cnt <- c(0)

df %>%
  filter(action_ID == value, variable == "Comment") %>%
  mutate(cnt = cnt + 1) %>%
  select(action_ID, cnt)
```

The output will be a dataframe with a new column `cnt` holding the desired values.
The problem with your example is that your criteria is not met.

Answer (score 0):

You're making it harder than it needs to be  with the loop:

Because it sounds like you want to link the count of comments by value back to the corresponding `action_ID`, it makes sense to count the comments by `value` first, then join back to the main data frame.

```
require(dplyr)

# create some data that mirrors yours

set.seed(1112124)
df <- data.frame(    
    action_ID= seq(1,10),
    variable = sample(c("Photo","Post","Share","Comment"),10,replace=T),
    value = sample(1:10,10,replace=T)
)


# first we tag each row with whether or not it's a comment (1 or 0)
Comments <- df %>% mutate(Comment = ifelse(variable=="Comment",1,0)) %>% 

  # then group by value because we want to summarize at that level
  group_by(value) %>% 
  # then add up the number of comments for each ID
  summarize(N_Comments = sum(Comment))

  # now add our comment counts back to the original action IDs
left_join(df, Comments, by = c("action_ID"="value"))


   action_ID variable value N_Comments
1          1    Photo     5         NA
2          2  Comment     7         NA
3          3     Post     6         NA
4          4  Comment     5         NA
5          5    Share     9          1
6          6  Comment     7          0
7          7     Post    10          2
8          8     Post    10          1
9          9  Comment    10          0
10        10  Comment     8          1
```